# data table is not reloading after fixed columns declaration in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to reload the datatable after some action like update and insert. 1st column is fixed   column ,If I am using fixed column code ,data table is not reloading ,Please anyone tell me how to avoid the conflict, Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var datetime = $.now();
table=$('#ReportTable').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sScrollX": "100%", //This is what made my columns increase in size.
    "sDom": '<"H"TClr>t<"F"ip>',
    "oTableTools": 
       {
         "sSwfPath": "/itmsmaps/htdocs/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
         "aButtons": [
                          {
                               "sExtends": "xls",
                               "mColumns": [ 0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7],
                               "sFileName": "MAPSResults - "+datetime+".csv"
                           },
                         ]

         },

    "ajax" :{

        url: 'ajax_call.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action:'loadData'
        }   
    },
    "columnDefs": [ 
                   { 
                    "mData": null, 
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mRender": function(data, type, full)
                     {
                         id=full[8];
                         var returnval = "<td><div class='main'><div class='panel'><a  href=#join_form  id='join_pop' onclick=\"addData('"+id+"','edit');\">Edit</a></div></div>";
                         returnval += "<div class='main'><div class='panel'><a href=#join_form  id='join_pop' onClick=\"deleteData('"+id+"');\">Delete</a></div></div></td>";
                         return returnval;
                     },
                   "aTargets":8  // this your column of action        
                    }
                  ]


});

new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table, {
     leftColumns: 1
 } );

});

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure fixedcolumns works with v1.9?

Comment: I have used these files:                                            <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.0.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.0.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded those fixed column JS files to local environment ,then it is working